# In vim, is there a way to :set an option only if it is not set yet?

Tags: vim, configuration, editor

Specifically, I'd like to set the makeprg option only if it has not been changed yet. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the contents of an option using `&`. So in this case you could check if the option is "empty" like this:

```
if &makeprg == ""
    set makeprg=new_value
endif
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Xavier makes the good point that the default value of `makeprg` is not an empty string. You can use `set {option}&` to set an option to its default, so the following can be used to change the value only if the current value is the default:

```
function! SetMakePrg( new_value )
    let cur_value=&makeprg
    " let new_val=a:new_value
    set makeprg& 
    if &makeprg == cur_value
        " cur_value is default: set to new value
        exe "set makeprg=" . a:new_value
    else
        " cur_value is not default: change it back
        exe "set makeprg=" . cur_value
    endif
endfunction
```

So calling `call SetMakePrg("my_make")` will modify the option only if it is not currently the default.

Comment: I am not sure the default value of makeprg is empty, I guess the default is 'make' (but it might vary depending on OS, etc).`:verbose set makeprg?` returns makeprg=make without file name so I guess this means it is the default value.